# Ruby - Compare Arrays and Swap Indexes

Tags: arrays, ruby, indexing, compare-and-swap

I have arrays of strings and arrays of integers that represent the indexes of the strings and the order they need to be swaped. I need to swap the index X with the following index, and do the same to the next pair of numbers.

I figure there's gotta be a way to replace the string's indexes with the numbers and swap the string position accordingly.

For example:

````
```
Array = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
SwapIndexes = [4, 2, 0, 3, 1, 5]
`#=>can also be understood as [4<to>2, 0<to>3, 1<to>5]`
```
````

Output should be:

````
```
NewArray = ["D", "F", "E", "A", "C", "B"]
`#=>Indexes have beem swaped according to each pair of numbers in SwapIndexes`
```
````

Answer (score 3):

Input

```
Array = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
SwapIndexes = [4, 2, 0, 3, 1, 5]
```

Code

```
SwapIndexes.each_slice(2) do |first, second|
  Array[first], Array[second] = Array[second], Array[first]
end
p Array
```

Output

```
["D", "F", "E", "A", "C", "B"]
```